How can I read a text file line by line in java with an indication of the offset and byte limit?
I have a text file of many lines. For example, a file of 10,000 bytes in size. Bytes of the digital signature are added to the file. I can calculate the size of these added bytes (for example, it's 500 bytes).
How do I line by line (without loading the entire file into memory!) read from 0 to 9500 bytes?

By using a BufferedReader!?

Is this signature appended or prepended? Is the sig. in 'binary' form or is it encoded as text (e.g. via Base64 encoding)?

@luk2302 If I use "BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)" and specify the size 9500 in sz, will all 9500 bytes be loaded into memory?!

@g00se The digital signature has already been added. It's a magical set of bytes. The library that adds this signature considers any file (even text) like a regular set of bytes. And the library will insert its digital signature after the last byte +500 bytes.

I'm not sure I understand the question. It looks like you want to read the file one-line-at-a-time while keeping a total of number of bytes read. Is that correct? Or, do you want to read the file with random access?

@OldDogProgrammer Bytes of text file: 0--------------9500---10000 , how i can reads of lines between 0 and 9500 not loading full file? Just one character at a time and counting bytes?

Tricky. One thing you might try is to search the file and find the number of linefeeds between offsets 0 and filesize-500. Then you will know when to stop reading lines in the normal way (the binary footer might contain 'linefeeds')

@g00se Good idea! However, the last line of the file may not have a newline. And immediately after the bytes of the last line, the magic bytes of the digital signature will begin.

Well a text file should have that. But DuncG's answer is better

You could define a FilterInputStream which limits the number of bytes read from any source. All this needs is an alternative version of the 2 read calls which stop serving more data when the byte limit is reached:
class MaxLimitInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    private final int limit;
    private int count;

    protected MaxLimitInputStream(InputStream in, int max) {
        super(in);
        this.limit = max;
    }
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int rc = count < limit ? super.read() : -1;
        if (rc != -1) {
            count++;
        }
        return rc;
    }
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        int rc = count < limit ? super.read(b, off, Math.max(0, Math.min(len, limit-count))) : -1;
        if (rc != -1) {
            count += rc;
        }
        return rc;
    }
}

Then you can use BufferedReader which has a MaxLimitInputStream somewhere in the chain. For example, this truncates a file read to whatever byte limit you expect. Example
int maxBytes = 9501;
try(var br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new MaxLimitInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Path.of("whatever.txt")), maxBytes)))) {
    br.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}

Please note that if you miscalculate maxBytes it may not correspond to exact number of characters and could truncate the last character read if part of a multi-byte sequence.

The perfect solution! Thank you. You added the use of a BufferedReader, instead of reading and checking one character at a time.
